Force Android to use mobile data even if other network interfaces are available?
I have an Android device that's used for mobile testing. This device has cell connectivity and is separately connected to the local network over ethernet (which is used for ADB).
How can I configure the Android device so that it uses mobile cell data to access the internet and NOT the ethernet connection?
adb shell ifconfig lists the active network interfaces:
eth0      Link encap:UNSPEC    Driver r8152
          inet addr:192.168.1.194  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::acc9:34c6:24a1:f137/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:559025 TX bytes:84086 

rmnet_data0 Link encap:UNSPEC  
          inet addr:10.76.204.250  Mask:255.255.255.252 
          inet6 addr: 2600:380:c034:e7ed:b901:d247:67b4:d598/64 Scope: Global
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1430  Metric:1
          RX packets:8811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:6886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7386188 TX bytes:1569087 

...

Looking to set rmnet_data0 (mobile data) to be the network interface used for internet instead of eth0.
adb shell ip route shows:
10.76.204.248/30 dev rmnet_data0 proto kernel scope link src 10.76.204.250 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.194

Possible approaches:

Overwriting iproutes or some other Unix networking sorcery (not very familiar with networking!)
Using adb shell service call connectivity to interact with IConnectivityManager (not sure this works - there doesn't seem to be any function that directly allows us to control the active network interface)
Potentially overriding Android's internal network scoring logic as described in this old SO question
It appears to be possible to override the network interface from within a particular app (as described here) but I don't control the app

Any pointers greatly appreciated!
